# Can't find r-base package

Tags: debian, apt, r

I'm using Debian 9.1 and tried to install the r-base using the command

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

But it says that it can't find the r-base package.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before it? Maybe there is a dependency that needs to be corrected or upgraded.

Comment: Yes I just typed the command that you suggested but it's still the same problem, still says that it can't find the package.

Comment: Please paste the outpuf of `apt-cache policy` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this first

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

just to make sure all packages are configured. Next, try

```
sudo apt-get -f install r-base
```

The `-f` flag will indicate `apt-get` to try and fix broken dependencies already installed.

If that doesn't work, you can try and install `r-base` package by following *similar* steps as `apt-get` basically does for you:

1. Go to [Debian packages (r-base)](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/r-base) and download the package manually. You will get a `.deb` file.
2. Open up your terminal and navigate to where the downloaded file is stored (probably in `$HOME/Downloads`).
3. Install package using `dpkg` and `-i` flag for install like this

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i rbase333.deb
   ```

   Substitute of course `rbase333.deb` with exact name of the file.

This should most certainly work. If not, you are having some "serious" problems that yet need to be discovered.